# C++ - implementation of string class

Tags: c++, arrays, string, implementation, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to implement string class. Here is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class MyString{
    private:
    char * content;
    int length;
    public:
    MyString ();
    MyString ( const char * );
    ~MyString ();
    MyString ( const MyString & );
    void print ( void );
    void operator = ( const MyString );
};

MyString :: MyString () {
    content = 0;
    length = 0;    
}

MyString :: MyString(const char *n) {
    length = strlen (n);
    content = new char [ length ];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
    content [i] = n [i];
    }
    content [length] = '\0';
    }


MyString :: ~ MyString () {
    delete [] content;
    content = 0;
}


MyString :: MyString ( const MyString & x ) {
    length = x.length;
    content = new char [length];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
    content [i] = x.content [i];
    }
    content [length] = '\0';
}

void MyString :: print( void ) {
    cout <<""<< content << endl;
}

void MyString :: operator = ( const MyString x ) {
    length = x.length;
    content = new char [length];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
    content [i] = x.content [i];
    }
    content [length] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    MyString word1 ("stackoverflow");
    MyString word2;
    word2 = word1;
    word1.print();
    word2.print();
}
```

I compiled it and this is what I get:

stackoverflow

stackoverflow

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.050 s
Press any key to continue.

Although it looks correct according to result above, I wonder is it really correct? I'm not so familiar with C-style strings so I'm concerned
for example about line:

```
content [length] = '\0';
```

Since C-style strings has null terminator at end, I wanted to terminate my array but is this correct way to do it? 
I used dynamic memory allocation and I also wonder did I free resources properly?
Are there some memory leaks?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:
I also overloaded opeartor + (I want to join "MyStrings"), here is code:

```
MyString MyString :: operator + ( const MyString & x ){
    MyString temp;
    temp.length = x.length + length;
    temp.content = new char [ temp.length +  1 ];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while ( i < temp.length ) {
    if (i < length ) {
    temp.content [i] = content [i];
    }
    else {
    temp.content [i] = x.content [j];
    j ++;
    }
    i ++;
    }
    temp.content [ temp.length ] = '\0';
    return temp;
    }
```

Here is main program:

```
int main()
   {
   MyString word1 ( "stack" );
   MyString word2 ( "overflow" );
   MyString word3 = word1 + word2;
   word3.print();
   word3 = word2 + word1;
   word3.print();
   }
```

And here is result:

stackoverflow

overflowstack

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.040 s
Press any key to continue.

I hope there are no problems with this code :)

EDIT2:
Here is implementation of + operator using for loops, instead of while:

```
MyString MyString :: operator + (const MyString & x){
    MyString temp;
    temp.length = x.length + length;
    temp.content = new char [temp.length+1];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
    temp.content[i] = content[i];
    }
    for( int i = length , j = 0 ; i <temp.length ; i++, j++){
    temp.content[i] = x.content[j];
    }
    content[temp.length] = '\0';
    return temp;
}
```

It's maybe better now because there is no if :)

Comment: I hope this is an assignment. The last thing the C++ world needs is yet another string class.

Comment: Don't worry, it is assignment :)

Comment: Your assignment of `content [length] = '\0'` overruns your allocation by one char. If you want to add NULL then you need to allocate length + 1 chars.

Comment: In my opinion BSTR is a pretty good implementation. If I were you I'd hunt down the source and study it carefully. It's declared in `comutil.h` but I don't have C++ on this system so I can't be more specific.

Comment: @etf: Just run from 0 to length. Since `strlen` returned a valid value (or you can assume that it did) then you *know* there is a 0 at the end. Just copy it as your string's terminator.

Comment: STUDENTS TAKE NOTE - see how much help you get when you make an effort then ask for *assistance* instead of trying to get us to do your homework!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign `content[length]` a value, but you haven't allocated enough memory for `content[length]` to be accessed. If `length == 10`, then you can access `content[0]` thru `content[9]`, but not `content[10]`.

This can be fixed of course by removing the line `content[length] = \0` from both constructors, or if you want to append `\0` you should increase the value of `length` by `1`.

Have you considered just using `std::string` internally?

Edit: @Thane Plummer was first to point this out in the comments!

Answer (score 3):

A few other notes and suggestions because there are are least two more gotchas waiting to leap out and strike.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// using namespace std; DANGER! namespace std is huge. Including all of it can
// have tragic, unforeseen consequences. Just use what you need.
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class MyString
{
private:
    char * content;
    int length;
// will use clone to reduce duplication in the copy constructor and operator =
    void copy(const MyString & source);
public:
    MyString();
// it is nice to name the variables in the definition. The header may be the
// only documentation the user gets.
    MyString(const char * source);
    ~MyString();
    MyString(const MyString &source);
    void print(void);
// changed prototype to match the expected format operator= format
    MyString & operator =(const MyString &source);
//OP asked about this in a previous question.
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                                     const MyString& towrite);
};

MyString::MyString()
{
//    content = 0; 
//destructor needs something to delete[]. If content isn't set to something,
//you'll get a big ka-BOOM! when the MyString is destroyed

    content = new char[1];
    content[0] = '\0'; //this has the advantage of printing an empty MyString 
                       // without crashing
    length = 0;
}


MyString::MyString(const char *source) // Variable names should describe their purpose
{
    //DANGER: strlen will fail horribly if passed an unterminated string. At a
    // loss at the moment for a good, safe solution. Look into strnlen, but
    // even it can't help you here.
    length = strlen(source);
    content = new char[length + 1]; //Needed one extra character to fit the NULL
/* If we got this far without dying, strcpy is no threat which makes this redundant:
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        content[i] = n[i];
    }
    content[length] = '\0';
*/
    strcpy(content, source);
}

MyString::~MyString()
{
    delete[] content;
//    content = 0; string is gone. No need to clear this
}

void MyString::copy(const MyString & source)
{
    length = source.length;
    content = new char[length + 1];
// assuming that the source MyString is correctly formatted this is once again safe.
    strcpy(content, source.content);
}

MyString::MyString(const MyString & source)
{
    copy(source); // use the copy method
}

void MyString::print(void)
{
    cout << "" << content << endl;
}

MyString &MyString::operator =(const MyString &source)
{
    copy(source); // use the copy method again.
    return *this; // allows chaining operations
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                          const MyString& towrite)
{
    out << towrite.content;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    MyString word0;
    MyString word1("stackoverflow");
    MyString word2;
    word2 = word1;
    MyString word3(word2); //testing copy constructor
    word1.print();
    word2.print();
    cout << word3 << endl; //testing outstream overload
    // test output of empty string
    word0.print(); 
    cout << word0 << endl; 
}
```

Edit:

Realized after posting that since we know the lengths of the strings, there are significant performance gains from using `memcpy(content, source.content, length+1);` in place of `strcpy`.

Comment: @etf Saw it. Most of the points I make above apply to it as well. Look into strcat and memcpy rather than making your own copy loops.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I can now go back to my previous problem (previous question involving classes Student and Word) :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors. One has already been stated by Thane Plummer in the comments and by Tas in the answers:

```
MyString :: MyString(const char *n) {
  length = strlen(n);
  content = new char [length];
  for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
    content [i] = x.content [i];
  }
  content [length] = '\0';
}
```

if your string is the null terminated "abc\0", strlen will return 3 and not 4, so you'll only allocate 3 chars instead of 4 (edit: and to be complete, as previously stated, you indeed start to index from 0 and not 1, so content[length] will always overflow, even if you increase length)

The other error is less grave (and is actually legal but odd c++):

```
void operator = ( const MyString );
```

The copy assignment operator should take a const reference rather than a const value (otherwise you may uselessly call the copy constructor), and return a reference rather than void (so that you can chain some calls). The correct declaration is:

```
MyString& operator=(const MyString&);
```

The correct implementation is:

```
MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& x) {
  length = x.length;
  delete[] content;
  content = new char [length];
  for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
    content [i] = x.content [i];
  }
  // actually not needed since x.content should already be null-terminated
  // content[length - 1] = '\0';
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: Your assignment operator leaks memory (failure to delete previous buffer )

Comment: you're right, i copied it without paying attention to that, i'll correct it

Comment: The `operator=` uses value is fine, but as you said, return reference is better than `void`. To see why using value is fine check "copy and swap" idiom here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: It is, but not with his original implementation, and before he can understand why the copy and swap works fine, he has to understand the difference between passing by value and passing by reference, and what they imply. (plus, it wouldn't work with a const value parameter as he originally specified)

Comment: If length is the number of characters in your string, and not the number of chars actually allocated (i.e. one more), the code seems correct. I would have used two for loops (the second with "shifted" indices) rather than a a while with an if, but it's just personal preference and i can't affirm it would be more efficient.
Of course, if you're allowed to use it, 2 memcpy would be potentially even more efficient (as user4581301 stated).