# heap corruption detected after normal block crt detected that the application

Tags: c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
    char* str;
    int size;
public:
    MyString()
    {
        str = '\0';
        size = 1;
    }
    MyString(const char* const s)
        : str(new char[strlen(s)])
    {
        size = strlen(s) + 1;
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
    MyString(const MyString& another)
        : str(new char[another.size])
    {
        size = another.size;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            str[i] = another.str[i];
    }
    ~MyString()
    {
        delete[] str;
    }
    void set(const char* st)
    {
        size = (int)strlen(st) + 1;
        str = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            str[i] = st[i];
    }
    bool isEqual(const MyString& other) const
    {
        if (size != other.size)
            return false;
        if (strcmp(str, other.str) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    void print() const
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << str[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyString strs[] = {
        MyString("C"),
        MyString(),
        MyString("Java")
    };
    strs[1].set("C++");

    const int arraySize = sizeof(strs) / sizeof(MyString);

    const MyString target("Java");
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        const MyString str(strs[i]); // copy constructor
        if (str.isEqual(target)) {
            cout << "[" << i << "]: ";
            str.print();
            break;
        }
    }
    for (const MyString& str : strs) {
        str.print();
    }
}
```

In dev c++ it's working and there was no caution, but in visual studio 2019, catution like "heap corruption detected after normal block crt detected that the application" is occured. I don't what is problem.

When I debuged my code, it successfully worked befor the main fuction finished. When destructor worked, the caution was appeared.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your default constructor should not compile with recent GCC compilers, you can only assign `NULL` or `nullptr` to pointer

```cpp
  MyString() {
    str = nullptr;
    size = 0;
  }
```

This constructor needs one extra 1 byte to allocate memory, then the buffer overflow can be avoided.

```cpp
  MyString(const char* const s) : str(new char[strlen(s) + 1]) {
    size = strlen(s) + 1;
    strncpy(str, s, size);
  }
```

`strncpy` is a safer replacement for `strcpy`, I suggest you use this one.

You also need to add implementation for `operator=`, or the compiler-generated one will cause a memory leak once you use `operator=` to copy an object.

```cpp
  MyString& operator=(const MyString& another) {
    if (&another == this) return *this;
    delete[] str;
    str = new char[another.size];
    size = another.size;
    // better to use strncpy here
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) str[i] = another.str[i];
    return *this;
  }
```

A similar string implementation is discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713654/c-implementation-of-string-class), you may also reference the code there.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cc1dhMjoa)

Comment: ahhhhhhh yayyyy thanks a lot. I corrected my code at MyString(const char* const s) constructor with initializer str(new char[strlen(s) + 1]). This was an simple error... Thanks a lot and have a nice day! -From South Korea Student :)

Comment: @iamianpark Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

***One*** problem is the initialization of the members in the default constructor:

```
str = '\0';
size = 1;
```

The character literal `'\0` is equal to zero, which is equal to a null pointer. That assignment is equivalent to:

```
str = nullptr;
```

And yet you still say that the size of the string is `1`, which is wrong since there is no string and the size should be zero.

---

***Another*** (and the likely culprint of your problem) problem is that in your constructor `MyString(const char* const s)` you use `strlen` to get the length of a C-style null-terminated string for the allocation, but you forget that `strlen` doesn't count the null-terminator.

This means the allocation will be too small, and when you use `strcpy` to copy the string it will write the null-terminator out of bounds of your allocated memory.

---

Furthermore, you in other places count with the null-terminator, and actually set the size to include the null-terminator (even in the `MyString(const char* const s)` constructor). This goes against the normal C++ semantics of strings where the size doesn't include the terminator.

This could then lead to further problems, like in your `print` function where you actually print the null-terminator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also corrected my code at constructor MyString(const char* const s) 
 : str(new char[strlen(s) + 1]) like this! This initializer was main problem i think. Thanks for your good comment and have a nice day! -From South Korea